# React-hook-form: Error messages not displayed after form submission. I need to reload the page manually

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form and yup to validate my form field input.
I also use the `ErrorMessage` component from react-hook-form to display multiple messages.
I have an issue: when I submit the form, and after that immediately enter invalid input in the field, then the error message is not displayed.
However, my submit button is disabled which means the validation kicks in but the message is not displaying.
After I reload the page manually, then everything starts working as expected - the error messages are displayed again.

Here are the snippets from my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";
import validationSchema from "../validations/validationSchema";

export default function Report(props) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    // reValidateMode: "onChange",
    criteriaMode: "all",
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      closedBugs: "",
    },
  });

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    closedBugs: "",
    reportedIncidents: "",
    reportedBugs: "",
  });

  const onFormSubmit = (data, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onSubmit(state);
  };
    setState({
      ...state,
      [key]: value,
    });
  };

  const modifyBugsValues = (value) => {
    if (value === "") {
      // needed in order for yup to return required field validation in case of empty field
      return undefined;
    } else {
      // needed in order for yup to treat 1,2 as 1.2 and return integer validation
      value = value.replace(/,/g, ".");
      return value;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="ui segment report">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)} className="ui form">
          <h4 className="ui dividing header">Project information</h4>
          <h4 className="ui dividing header">Bug metrics</h4>
          <div className="three fields">
            <div className="field mandatory-metric">
              <label>closed bugs during month</label>
              <div className="field">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  {...register("closedBugs", {
                    setValueAs: modifyBugsValues,
                  })}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
                  name="closedBugs"
                  placeholder="1"
                  required
                />

                <ErrorMessage
                  errors={errors}
                  name="closedBugs"
                  render={({ messages }) => {
                    console.log("Messages" + JSON.stringify(messages));
                    return (
                      messages &&
                      Object.entries(messages).map(([type, message]) => (
                        <p className="error" key={type}>
                          {message}
                        </p>
                      ))
                    );
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="ui secondary large button"
            data-cy="submitBtn"
            disabled={!isValid}
            tabIndex={0}
          >
            Submit report
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: any solutions for that problem? I have the same issue that no errors are shown. "<FormErrorMessage>" is working but not the "<ErrorMessage>" Component from RHF

Comment: @larz yes, it has been resolve in Github https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/10327 (using mode=onBlur but reValidationMode=onChange therefore it has been conflict between validation and re-validation stategy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on Github https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/10327
using mode=onBlur but reValidationMode=onChange therefore it has been a conflict between validation and re-validation strategy.